# Rotation Matrix Spiraling inward

Tags: javascript, canvas, matrix

I am trying to make a square that rotates in place, however my square is spiraling inward, and I have no idea why. Here is the code, if someone could please explain what is happening as to why it is not just spinning in place.

```
var angle = 2 * (Math.PI / 180);
var rotate = [
  [Math.cos(angle),Math.sin(angle)],
  [-Math.sin(angle),Math.cos(angle)]
];

var points = [[300,0],[0,300],[-300,0],[0,-300]];
init.ctx.translate(init.canvas.width/2,init.canvas.height/2);


function loop(){
  draw();
}
setInterval(loop,10);

function draw(){
  init.ctx.beginPath();
  init.ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[1][0],points[1][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[2][0],points[2][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[3][0],points[3][1]);
  init.ctx.closePath();
  init.ctx.stroke();
  for(let i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    init.ctx.beginPath();
    init.ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    init.ctx.fillRect(points[i][0],points[i][1],5,5);
    points[i][0] = points[i][0]*rotate[0][0] + points[i][1]*rotate[0][1];
    points[i][1] = points[i][0]*rotate[1][0] + points[i][1]*rotate[1][1];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are applying a small rotation each time draw is called, specifically 1/180th of a full rotation.  Problem is that you are relying on floating point math to give you exact values, and it's not because it doesn't.  This is compounded by the points array being calculated by iterations.  I suggest calculate the new points on each step through draw by applying the correct rotate matrix for your current angle to the starting points.

```
var angle = 0;

var startPoints = [[300,0],[0,300],[-300,0],[0,-300]];
var points = [[300,0],[0,300],[-300,0],[0,-300]];

init.ctx.translate(init.canvas.width/2,init.canvas.height/2);

function loop(){
  draw();
}
setInterval(loop,10);

function draw(){
  init.ctx.beginPath();
  init.ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[1][0],points[1][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[2][0],points[2][1]);
  init.ctx.lineTo(points[3][0],points[3][1]);
  init.ctx.closePath();
  init.ctx.stroke();
  angle = angle + Math.PI / 90;
    var rotate = [
      [Math.cos(angle),Math.sin(angle)],
      [-Math.sin(angle),Math.cos(angle)]
    ];
  for(let i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    init.ctx.beginPath();
    init.ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    init.ctx.fillRect(points[i][0],points[i][1],5,5);
    points[i][0] = startPoints[i][0]*rotate[0][0] + startPoints[i][1]*rotate[0][1];
    points[i][1] = startPoints[i][0]*rotate[1][0] + startPoints[i][1]*rotate[1][1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Some tips to improve your code.

As a beginner I can see some bad habits creeping in and as there is already an answer I thought I would just give some tips to improve your code.

---

- Don't use `setInterval` to create animations. `requestAnimationFrame` gives much better quality animations.

---

- Arrays were created in high level languages to make life easier, not harder.

You have painfully typed out

> ```
> init.ctx.beginPath();
> init.ctx.moveTo(points[0][0],points[0][1]);
> init.ctx.lineTo(points[1][0],points[1][1]);
> init.ctx.lineTo(points[2][0],points[2][1]);
> init.ctx.lineTo(points[3][0],points[3][1]);
> init.ctx.closePath();
> init.ctx.stroke();
> ```

That would be a nightmare if you had 100 points. Much better to create a generic function to do that for you.

```
function drawShape(ctx,shape){  
    ctx.beginPath();                            
    for(var i = 0; i < shape.length; i++){
       ctx.lineTo(shape[i][0], shape[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.closePath(); 
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Now you can render any shape on any canvas context with the same code.

```
drawShape(init.ctx,points);  // how to draw your shape.
```

---

- If you use a uniform scale then you can shorten the transform a little by reusing the x axis of the transformation

> ```
> var rotate = [
>   [Math.cos(angle),Math.sin(angle)],
>   [-Math.sin(angle),Math.cos(angle)]
> ];
> ```

Note how the second two values are just the first two swapped with the new x negated. You can also include a scale in that and just hold the first two values.

```
var angle = ?
var scale = 1; // can be anything

// now you only need two values for the transform
var xAx = Math.cos(angle) * scale;  // direction and size of x axis
var xAy = Math.sin(angle) * scale;
```

And you apply the transform to a point as follows

```
var px = ?;  // point to transform
var py = ?;
    
var tx = px * xAx - py * xAy;
var ty = px * xAy + py * xAx;
```

And to add a origin

```
var tx = px * xAx - py * xAy + ox;  // ox,oy is the origin
var ty = px * xAy + py * xAx + oy;
```

---

But is is much better to let the canvas 2D API do the transformation for you. The example below shows the various methods described above to render your box and animate the box.

### Example using best practice.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width; // w,h these are set if canvas is resized
var h = canvas.height;
var cw = w / 2; // center width
var ch = h / 2; // center height
var globalScale = 1; // used to scale shape to fit the canvas
var globalTime;

var angle = Math.PI / 2;
var rotateRate = 90; // deg per second

var points = [
  [300, 0],
  [0, 300],
  [-300, 0],
  [0, -300]
];
var maxSize = Math.hypot(600, 600); // diagonal size used to caculate scale 
                                    // so that shape fits inside the canvas


// Add path to the current path
// shape contains path points
// x,y origin of shape
// scale is the scale of the shape
// angle is the amount of rotation in radians.
function createShape(shape, x, y, scale, angle) {
  var i = 0;
  ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); // set the scale and origin
  ctx.rotate(angle); // set the rotation
  ctx.moveTo(shape[i][0], shape[i++][1]);
  while (i < shape.length) { // create a line to each point
    ctx.lineTo(shape[i][0], shape[i++][1]);
  }
}

// draws fixed scale axis aligned boxes at vertices.
// shape contains the vertices
// vertSize size of boxes drawn at verts
// x,y origin of shape
// scale is the scale of the shape
// angle is the amount of rotation in radians.
function drawVertices(shape, vertSize, x, y, scale, angle) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  const xAx = Math.cos(angle) * scale; // direction and size of x axis
  const xAy = Math.sin(angle) * scale;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < shape.length) {
    const vx = shape[i][0]; // get vert coordinate
    const vy = shape[i++][1]; // IMPORTANT DONT forget i++ in the while loop
    ctx.fillRect(
      vx * xAx - vy * xAy - vertSize / 2, // transform and offset by half box size
      vx * xAy + vy * xAx - vertSize / 2,
      vertSize, vertSize
    );
  }
}

// draws shape outline and vertices
function drawFullShape(shape, scale, angle, lineCol, vertCol, lineWidth, vertSize) {
  // draw outline of shape
  ctx.strokeStyle = lineCol;
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth / scale; // to ensure that the line with is 1 pixel
                                     // set the width to in inverse scale
  ctx.beginPath();
  // shape origin at cw,ch 
  createShape(shape, cw, ch, scale, angle);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  // draw the vert boxes.
  ctx.fillStyle = vertCol;
  drawVertices(shape, vertSize, cw, ch, scale, angle);
}


function loop(timer) {
  globalTime = timer;
  if (w !== innerWidth || h !== innerHeight) {  // check if canvas need resize
    cw = (w = canvas.width = innerWidth) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height = innerHeight) / 2;
    globalScale = Math.min(w / maxSize, h / maxSize);
  }
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  const innerAngle = globalTime * (rotateRate * (Math.PI / 180)) / 1000;

  drawFullShape(points, globalScale, angle, "black", "red", 2, 6);
  drawFullShape(points, globalScale * 0.5, innerAngle, "black", "red", 2, 6);
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```